# jQuery UI: how to open/close a dialog opened by another dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, overwrite

**index.php**

```
// load jquery.js and jquery.ui.js
$("#dialog_a").load("template_a.php").dialog();
$("#dialog_b").load("template_b.php").dialog();
```

**template_a.php**

```
just HTML, no JS
```

**template_b.php**

```
// !!! -> load jquery.js and jquery.ui.js <- !!!
$("#dialog").load("template_c.php").dialog({modal:true});
```

As you can see, I load two dialogs. #dialog_a just loads text without any function BUT #dialog_b loads a stand-alone-script which includes jquery and jquery.ui again.

After opening #dialog_b (by anchor/onclick) it's not possible to access objects in the index.php (e.g. closing a dialog). For me it seems like template_b.php overwrites the DOM. But I've no idea how to fix this problem. Do you have?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't load jQuery and jQueryUI again if you already have it in your main page.  take it out of your template_b.php

Comment: @adamb I had to google but now I know how this community works. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: use the [jQuery live() function](http://api.jquery.com/live/)!

**index.php**

```
$(".anchor_in_dialog_or_not_doesnt_matter").live("click", function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog();
});
```

**template_b.php**

```
if ($_GET["standalone"])
    // load jquery, jquery.ui
endif;
```

I hope it helps somebody!

**Edit**: As adamb already mentioned below, use on() instead of live()!

Comment: .live() is deprecated. Use .on() instead. [How to convert live() to on() in jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/)